# Bootstrap img responive, How does it work?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Hey I am using bootstrap and I am using images of same dimensions but I am getting two very different outputs I dont know the reason behing it, can any one help in this issue?
I am attaching screenshot :
[image: Ambiguous behaviour of img-responsive]

Here is the code:

```
    <div class="pdt" id="pdt">
      <div class="row product">
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="photos/3KG_P.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <p class="imgDescription">Capacity :3 KG</p>
        <input type="button" value="Ask Price" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fun6()">
       </div>
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3"><img src="photos/5KG_P.jpg" class="img-responsive"><p class="imgDescription">Capacity :5 KG</p><input type="button" value="Ask Price" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fun7()"></div><div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3"><img src="photos/8KG_P.jpg" class="img-responsive"><p class="imgDescription">Capacity :8 KG</p><input type="button" value="Ask Price" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fun8()"></div>
</div>
<div class="row product">

  <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3">
   <img src="photos/10KG_P.jpg" class="img-responsive"><p class="imgDescription">Capacity :10 KG</p><input type="button" value="Ask Price" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fun9()"></div>
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3"><img src="photos/15KG_P.jpg" class="img-responsive"><p class="imgDescription">Capacity :15 KG</p><input type="button" value="Ask Price" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fun10()"></div><div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3"><img src="photos/20KG_P.jpg" class="img-responsive"><p class="imgDescription">Capacity :20 KG</p><input type="button" value="Ask Price" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fun11()"></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is because those using the class `col-md-offset-1`

Try this:

```
<div class="pdt" id="pdt">
    <div class="row product">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="photos/3KG_P.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            <p class="imgDescription">Capacity :3 KG</p>
            <input type="button" value="Ask Price" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fun6()">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="photos/5KG_P.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            <p class="imgDescription">Capacity :5 KG</p>
            <input type="button" value="Ask Price" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fun7()">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="photos/8KG_P.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            <p class="imgDescription">Capacity :8 KG</p>
            <input type="button" value="Ask Price" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fun8()">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row product">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="photos/10KG_P.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            <p class="imgDescription">Capacity :10 KG</p>
            <input type="button" value="Ask Price" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fun9()">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="photos/15KG_P.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            <p class="imgDescription">Capacity :15 KG</p>
            <input type="button" value="Ask Price" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fun10()">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="photos/20KG_P.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            <p class="imgDescription">Capacity :20 KG</p>
            <input type="button" value="Ask Price" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fun11()">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```